# возможно ли сделать на своем сайте поделится в FB фотографией?

Tags: html

к примеру есть слайдер портфолио там только фото какую ссылку генерить или как чтобы клац на любую фотку и это фото загрузится на стену или куда там оно на фейсбук.

Спасибо!

Comment: Возможно, конечно. По клику парсите картинку и отправляете на стену через [facebook sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto/) (ссылка на php skd, в наличии и другие), заране надо учитывать что так могут делать только те, кто зашел на сайт под своим акком фб.

Comment: А можете подсказать с чего начать? Вот я установил my-server:my-php-project$ composer require facebook/graph-sdk

получу к примеру по клику ссылку на картинку а дальше что ? c помощью ajax отправлять на свой сервер, эту картинку? а там этот код https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto ?